# How to custom claims token to firebase firestore rules via Android App?

Tags: android, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I'm trying to customize claims token to firestore rule via Cloud Functions but it do not appear a good solution because it throws an exception when I try create an user via Android Application like follow:

> Caused by: io.grpc.StatusException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or
>   insufficient permissions.

I'm trying intercept the user creation by follow cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions'); 
const admin = require('firebase-admin'); 

admin.initializeApp();

exports.addAdminRole = functions.firestore
    .document("users/{user}")
    .onWrite((change, ctx) => {
        return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(ctx.auth.uid, {
            role: "ADMIN"
        })
});
```

Below it's the token customization **working via SIMULATOR!**

[image: Via simulator it's work fine]

What I need to do it?

Comment: There's not enough information here.  Please edit the question to illustrate exactly **how** you know the function code doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson check it now!

Comment: You will need to show the client code that doesn't work the way you expect, as well as confirmation that the client can't see the custom claims that were set in the function.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Without seeing all the information, I'll suggest that it's entirely possible that the custom claims have simply not propagated to the client.  A token refresh is require for the client (and the security rules triggered from that client) to use the updated claims.